# Launch image manager for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ipad, gimp

Table 5-4 (about half way down) this [Apple doc page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html) suggests sizes for the launch images for iOS:

```
Device                       Portrait                         Landscape 

iPhone and iPod touch     320 x 480 pixels                  Not supported
                          640 x 960 pixels (@2x)
iPhone 5                  640 x 1136 pixels (@2x)           Not supported         
iPad                      768 x 1024 pixels                 1024 x 768 pixels
                          1536 x 2048 pixels (@2x)          2048 x 1536 pixels (@2x)
```

My app has a photo background at launch so at present I have to use GIMP to crop/resize the photo for each of these, which is fiddly.

Is there a tool to do this automatically ?

One other complication is that there are a couple of logos in the image too, ideally they will be in separate layers, so they can stay legible and tidily laid out for each size/orientation.

Comment: I found a templste for Photoshop that might do the trick https://github.com/elistone/ios-splashscreen-template-v2/blob/master/README.md   Also Prepo app for Mac, though this only saves @2x versions, no auto cropping/rezising.

Comment: The PSD template isn't much good, it doesn't even rotate the screens for the Landscape mode. Reckon it would be easier to write a quickie Mac app to DIY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a tool that I know of do do this. But there is a button in the Xcode Organizer, under Screenshots, labeled “Save as Launch Image”. If you set up your code to dynamically generate the image you want, you can run your app on various devices and grab images of it running, and then use those images as your launch images. You may have to modify them a little bit, but it’s certainly easier than creating each one from scratch.

Comment: Update: on iOS 8, you can provide a xib for iOS to render as your launch image.

Comment: Found this which is useful for all the icons and start up screens http://makeappicon.com